# EL not working in jsp, possible mismatch between servlet api's?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jstl, el

I'm trying to test a simple webapp to work on a servlet container that only supports servlet api 2.3. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the 2.3 container yet so I tried testing on a recent version of tomcat.

I have the following setup:

- Tomcat 7, which has servlet api 3.0 and no standard JSTL support
- in my web.xml I declare to use servlet 2.3 as such:

`<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >`

- In one of my maven dependencies, I added the jstl library so it is now on my classpath:

  `<dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>`

Unfortunately, my EL doesn't work, they just get rendered as is. E.g.: ${2+2} is not shown as "4". Here's a snippet of my jsp page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<body>
    <h2>Hello World</h2>
    <c:out value="${2+2}"/>
</body>

</html>
```

So I assume this because I have mismatch between my web.xml declaration (saying it's 2.3) but my actual servlet container (tomcat) wants to use 3.0 with jstl 1.2. If I really wanted to make it work, I could update my web.xml to also use version 3.0. However, this would not work on the (other) servlet-container that is 2.3. So my question is, how can I test my 2.3 webapp, Is there an older version of tomcat that uses 2.3 aswell? Or is servlet 3.0 backwards compatible and did I misconfigure something?

Note: the actual loading of the pages and the webapp in general works fine, it's only the EL (${something}) that don't evaluate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using servlet version 2.3 or earlier than 2.3 then EL are by default disabled so you have to enable it means by default it is true as :

`isELIgnored ="true"`

you have to make it false.

but if you are useing later version of servlet than 2.3 then it is enabled by default means

`isELIgnored ="false"`

you can enable or desable by

```
<%@ page isELIgnored ="true|false" %>
```

at a time only one value you can give `true or false`.If it is true, EL expressions are ignored when they appear in static text or tag attributes. If it is false, EL expressions are evaluated by the container.

Answer (score 1):

Use `isELIgnored` in page tag

```
<%@ page language="java" 
contentType="text/html; 
charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"  
isELIgnored="false"%>
```

Answer (score 0):

First check do you have correct version of `jstl.jar` and `standard.jar` WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: No, nothing is in my lib folder. I use maven depedencies for compile reasons, and tomcat/lib for runtime. I'm pretty sure I've got all the required jsps because it works now (see other answers), they're just not in my web-inf/lib